# Why does phonegap not find Android when I set my path?

Tags: linux, android, path

I am trying to setup phonegap to build for android.

When I installed phonegape, it told me :

```
npm WARN engine ncallbacks@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.6.7"} (current: {"node":"0.12.5","npm":"2.11.2"})
-
> cordova@2.7.4 install /home/n07070/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova
> node bootstrap.js

SUCCESS: Minimum requirements for blackberry met.
BOOTSTRAPPING blackberry...
WARNING: Your system does not meet requirements to create wp8 projects. See error output below.
/bin/sh: 1: /home/n07070/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/lib/cordova-wp7/bin/check_reqs: not found

SKIPPING wp8 bootstrap.
WARNING: Your system does not meet requirements to create wp7 projects. See error output below.
/bin/sh: 1: /home/n07070/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/lib/cordova-wp7/bin/check_reqs: not found

SKIPPING wp7 bootstrap.
ERROR! Could not create a native blackberry project test fixture. See below for error output.
/home/n07070/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/lib/cordova-blackberry/bin/create: 26: [: /home/n07070/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/spec/fixtures/projects/native/blackberry_fixture: unexpected operator
/home/n07070/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/lib/cordova-blackberry/bin/create: 52: /home/n07070/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/lib/cordova-blackberry/bin/create: function: not found

WARNING: Your system does not meet requirements to create android projects. See error output below.
The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your path. Output: /bin/sh: 1: android: not found

SKIPPING android bootstrap.
WARNING: Your system does not meet requirements to create ios projects. See error output below.
Xcode is (probably) not installed, specifically the command `xcodebuild` is unavailable or erroring out. Output of `xcodebuild -version` is: /bin/sh: 1: xcodebuild: not found

SKIPPING ios bootstrap.
phonegap@0.9.4 node_modules/phonegap
├── colors@0.6.2
├── semver@1.1.0
├── qrcode-terminal@0.9.5
├── shelljs@0.0.9
├── optimist@0.3.7 (wordwrap@0.0.3)
├── node-static@0.6.9 (mime@1.3.4)
├── phonegap-build@0.8.0 (qrcode-terminal@0.8.0, phonegap-build-api@0.3.3)
├── prompt@0.2.14 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.6, winston@0.8.3, utile@0.2.1)
└── cordova@2.7.4 (ncallbacks@1.0.0, open@0.0.3, shelljs@0.1.2, elementtree@0.1.3, xcode@0.5.1, request@2.11.4, prompt@0.2.7, express@3.0.6, plugman@0.5.6, ripple-emulator@0.9.29, plist@0.4.0)
```

But ! My $PATH is :

```
$ $PATH
sh: 1: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/media/HDD/Code/android-sdk-linux/plateform-tools:/media/HDD/Code/android-sdk-linux/tools: not found
```

But, when I look :

```
$ cd /media/HDD/Code/android-sdk-linux/
$ ls
add-ons  build-tools  docs  extras  platforms  platform-tools  samples  SDK Readme.txt  sources  system-images  temp  tools
```

I see that there is an error in my $PATH, but how do I fix that ?
Is they a simple way to remove phonegap and the android sdk, fix my path back to it's original state and start all over again ?